# Tuleap - Assign the artifact to User Groups

Tags: artifacts, usergroups, tuleap

We have implemented tuleap to my organisation and we have some 5 internal groups. I have created a tracker with new artifacts is only bind to user-groups and not to users.

So, when a new artifact was created the team member will only select the user group.

In semantics there is a option only for bind to users. (Since i have selected only bindto usergroups alone, the artifact is not transferring to the respective group).

Is it possible to make the artifact is bind to the user groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible to have the assigned_to semantic bound to user groups